# C# COM Exception: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))

Tags: c#, excel, exception, com, interop

For some reason I have started to get the below exception in my code after it has been working perfectly for over 6 months. There have been no code changes at all but here is the main bit of the exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010108): The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)) at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.Save() at ditCreditEMGTestAutomationDifferenceEngine.Comparers.ExcelComparer.performProcessClean() in
```

And the code it seems to be referencing:

```
    private void performProcessClean()
    {   
        xlWorkBook1.Save();
        xlWorkBook2.Save();
        xlWorkBook1 = null;
        xlWorkBook2 = null;
        xlApp.Quit();
    }
```

I've tried the dll's on two seperate machines where they have been working fine previously but see the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Excel did crash. The code RPC_E_DISCONNECTED is returned when the COM call into the target process did not succeed. This is normally a sign that the process was corrupted somehow. Were new Excel addins installed?

Comment: What's changed? If it's not your code then it must be something else on those machines

Answer (score 0):

Installed any updates? Service Packs?